# Blocking availability for events at Google Calendar doesn't work as it is expected

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I wanted to create busy event at a specific time range. And I created it using [Google Calendar API Event Reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations). In the document it says there is transparency parameter for this usage.

> "opaque" - The event blocks time on the calendar. This is the default value.

I gave this value for transparency parameter. But then I was able to create another event at this time. But I want to lock this time when an event created as busy so noone can take event at this time no longer. Am I using wrong parameter? If I am which parameter I should use?

Comment: you can check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918917/google-calendar-api-event-free-busy-blocking-data)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Automatically declining events lab is not exposed via the API so the only way to get the behavior you want is for secondary calendars. You can go into the secondary calendar's settings page in the UI and set "Auto-accept invitations" to "Auto-accept invitations that do not conflict." Then creating an "opaque" event will decline all overlapping invitations that come afterwards.