# Get Busy/Free status from an event in Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, calendar, google-calendar-api

I need to get the "Show me as" status of a particular event (not a calendar) from Google calendar API.

I have highlighted the section which I need the value of:

[image]

I went here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events in their documentation and couldn't find it.

Is there any way to get that?

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy) the free/busy is only specific for the calendar not an event. So maybe it is not yet available to get a specific events. Try to check this related [SO ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338320/getting-show-me-available-busy-value-in-google-calendar-events-net-api?noredirect=1&lq=1) that I found if it can help you and give you another idea about this issue.

Comment: Wow! So Transparency property is what I have to use to determine Free/Busy status for events. Thanks @KENdi for sharing that ticket. I appreciate that.